# Assigning a group level access in Android APK

Tags: android, permissions, apk, android-manifest

In android app, can we allow permissions to w/r/x certain files/directories?, I'm talking about /data or some other folder. I want to get it working on un-rooted one?

If yes what permission levels should I grant in my manifest? Please help.